# Can bleach be sufficient to cleanse for Passover?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, passover, chametz-leaven, kashering-kosherization

A couple years ago I (Conservative) was asked by my wife (Baptist) 
to educate her church by running a Seder for them.   I cleaned the
kitchen and serving areas as best I could, vacuumed the carpets,
and moved the chametz off-site.  Boiling was unrealistic, so
my main cleaning agents for dishes and utensils were soap, hot 
water, and bleach.

**Since bleach sterlizes, is that sufficent for
rendering anything touching food fit for Passover?**

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: it might serve some useful purpose, but still no.

Comment: If the Baptists were not Jewish why would they be concerned about the fitness of the food for Passover?

Comment: Furthermore, boiling would be insufficient for many kitchen utensils such as the oven.  For that, you'd better hope it has a self-cleaning cycle or get ready to pull out your handy blowtorch (or setting the temperature really high for a long time, but where's the fun in that?).

Comment: Avrohom, it might not have mattered to them, but it mattered to me. I wanted to give them as authentic an experience as possible given the resources I had available.

Comment: Somewhat related to the background information in the question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27094

Comment: @Aule, please [register your account](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login). Then you'll be able to comment on your own questions (among other [benefits of registering](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557)).

Answer (score 1):

Star-K has an entire [article](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-passover-kashering.htm) dedicated to kashering for Pesach.  Different types of utensils require different methods for kashering them.  Bleach is not even mentioned in the article, so I think it's safe to assume that it doesn't do the trick.

**Edit**

Well... it seems that according to [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18177/1713), the Chazon Ish holds that it's ok to kasher using bleach, even l'chatchila.

Comment: Re your edit: He was talking about performing *hag'ala* with a boiling bleach/water solution, not just scrubbing with bleach.